# String values in SQLalchemy showing as NULL

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to insert data from a .csv file into a sqlalchemy table - All data types apart from Strings are correctly inserted into the table.

An example of the csv data is:

```
Version=1.1
636706156850400000,-1.54752188,53.79451,HUL4,3809,20,1014.63495,M
636706156850800000,-1.54752056,53.7945102,HUL4,3809,20,1014.53614,M
636706156851200000,-1.54751925,53.7945104,HUL4,3809,20,1014.43734,M
```

The relevant python code is:

```
class Gpxmm_Coverage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Gpxmm_Coverage'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False) 
    gps = Column(Integer)
    x = Column(Float)
    y = Column(Float)
    elr = Column(String)
    trid = Column(Integer)
    m = Column(Integer)
    yards = Column(Float)
    type = Column(String)
```

However, when browsing the data (using DB browser for SQLite on Mac), elr and type columns are as showing 'NULL'. All other columns have the correct value types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure `elr` and `type` is `str` when you load them from csv.
2. The docs recommended specifying `length` argument for `String` type, e.g. Column(String(64))

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String